# Why is my program hanging

Tags: python, while-loop

```
from random import *

IQ = []
row1 = ["#", "#", "#"]
row2 = ["#", "#", "#"]
row3 = ["#", "#", "#"]
board = [row1, row2, row3]


def Display_Board():
    print(row1[0],"|", row1[1], "|", row1[2])
    print("----------")
    print(row2[0],"|", row2[1], "|", row2[2])
    print("----------")
    print(row3[0],"|", row3[1], "|", row3[2])

def Automated_Move(board):
    while True:
        RandomMove = randint(0,2)
        if board[RandomMove][RandomMove] == "#":
            board[RandomMove][RandomMove] = "O"
            break
        elif board[RandomMove][RandomMove] != "#":
            pass

while True:
    #print(IQ)
    Display_Board()
    Row = int(input("Row: ")) - 1
    Col = int(input("Col: ")) - 1
    if board[Row][Col] != "X" and board[Row][Col] != "O":
        board[Row][Col] = "X"
        IQ.append(Row)
        IQ.append(Col)
    elif board[Row][Col] == "X" or board[Row][Col] == "O":
        print("This is already Taken")
        pass

    Automated_Move(board)
    print("\n")
```

I'm trying to make a simple Genetic Algorithm Based Tic-Tac-Toe and I have no idea why it is crashing.
I figured out it is in the loop of the Automated_Move Function (If that helps)

Comment: You realize that you're only checking 3 of the 9 possible spots, right?

Comment: if its crashing, the output of the crash would be helpful

Comment: It's not crashing it is just hanging and won't do anything and I thought that It would treat it as a grid doing it like that

Comment: Josh Hamlet was Right it was only going through 3 of the positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main loop never ends. There is no `break` in:

```
while True:
    #print(IQ)
    Display_Board()
    Row = int(input("Row: ")) - 1
    Col = int(input("Col: ")) - 1
    if board[Row][Col] != "X" and board[Row][Col] != "O":
        board[Row][Col] = "X"
        IQ.append(Row)
        IQ.append(Col)
    elif board[Row][Col] == "X" or board[Row][Col] == "O":
        print("This is already Taken")
        pass

    Automated_Move(board)
    print("\n")
```

Also your `Automated_Move()`'s `while` loop also sooner or later will get into a forever loop.

```
def Automated_Move(board):
    while True:
        RandomMove = randint(0,2)
        if board[RandomMove][RandomMove] == "#":
            board[RandomMove][RandomMove] = "O"
            break
        elif board[RandomMove][RandomMove] != "#":
            pass
```

This loop breaks only if there is a `'#'` element in `board` (after changing that element to `O`). After several iterations, all (diagonal) elements of the `board` will be `'O'` and so the loop will never exit.

One possible solution is to modify the main loop as:

```
if any(['#' in r for r in board]):
    Automated_Move(board)
else:
    break
```

Comment: Cause I will add a function in later that allows the person to quit so for now I'm just making the AI part of it work

Comment: @MorganHarrison I added an analysis of your `Automated_Move()` loop.

Comment: With the Current program I have it so that the loser will always start so that the program can continuously run and allow the program to learn later on